# Is there any way I can keep wallet unlocked and open all the time on the local node

Tags: cleos, keosd

In V1.5 there is no way wallet timeout can be set.
Is there any way keeping wallet open/unlocked all the time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm still seeing the option under `keosd -h` for help.

```
keosd --version v1.5.0

--unlock-timeout arg (=900)           Timeout for unlocked wallet in seconds
                                        (default 900 (15 minutes)). Wallets
                                        will automatically lock after specified
                                        number of seconds of inactivity.
                                        Activity is defined as any wallet
                                        command e.g. list-wallets.
```

Command:

`keosd --unlock-timeout=9999999`

Comment: No problem, nice hat