# unlock-timeout keosd issues and keosd connection

Tags: keosd

I'd like to change the length of time a wallet stays unlocked. I tried two things:

1) I directly modified the `config.ini` file so that `unlock-timeout = 40000`.

2) I tried `keosd --unlock-timeout == 4000000` just like [here](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/3506/is-there-any-way-i-can-keep-wallet-unlocked-and-open-all-the-time-on-the-local-n).

In the first case, the file did change, but it did not change the behavior, i.e., I still get logged out of the wallet every 15 minutes of no inactivity.

In the second case, it does not work and it says `warn  2019-02-07T17:49:30.317 thread-0  wallet_plugin.cpp:68          plugin_initialize    ] 3120000 wallet_exception: Wallet exception Failed to lock access to wallet directory; is another keosd running?`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I second case, you have to run the `keosd` as a new process. For that, you have to kill currently running `keosd` process first.

Run `pkill keosd` for stopping currently running `keosd` and then run

```
keosd --unlock-timeout == 4000000
```

If it is not working,

```
ps -ef | grep keosd
```

This will return the pid of keosd if already running.
Then run

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

Then run `keosd --unlock-timeout == 4000000`

Good Luck !!!

Comment: The `keosd` was run before hence after `pkill keosd` it has solved. Thanks.